# Neo4J Cypher: Returning results from partially matched indexed lookup queries

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am calling service methods and I want to know if any of the nodes do not exist. I do not want to run multiple queries

```
START l=node:node_auto_index(UserIdentifier = 'USER1'), f=node:node_auto_index(UserIdentifier = 'USER2')
CREATE UNIQUE f-[fo:FOLLOWS]->l
RETURN l, f, fo;
```

I want to return meaningful error messages to the client that tell if 'USER1' exists, if 'USER2' exists and if the follows relationship exists. Presently this query will return nothing if USER1 or USER2 does not exist. If they both do the results are fine. How do I return

```
l = USER1
f = NULL (or equivalent value that will tell me the user doesn't exist)
fo = NULL (or equivalent value that will tell me the user doesn't exist)
```

if only USER1 exists?

Answer (score 0):

coalesce(rec_part.DW_FLAG?,"NULLLLLLLL")
You can use `coalesce` as shown here [functions-coalesce](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-functions-scalar.html#functions-coalesce)

So, if you want to use it with `String` values, it may be like this:

```
START l=node:node_auto_index(UserIdentifier = 'USER1'), f=node:node_auto_index(UserIdentifier = 'USER2')
CREATE UNIQUE f-[fo:FOLLOWS]->l
RETURN coalesce(l.SOMETHING,"Value doesn't exist")
```

Comment: I tried this, it doesn't seem to work, I'm wondering if the indexed lookup is the problem